# How do I pass a smart pointer from a function to the caller?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm trying to grasp the concept of smart pointers in C++. I have the following piece of code (a unit test using GoogleTest):

```
TEST(SHT35Sensor, ValidInstruction) {
    auto sht35 = SampleSHT35::create();
    sht35->add(22.4, 56.5);
    char writeBuffer[100] = {0};
    auto serial = std::make_unique<SampleSerial>("", writeBuffer, 0);
    auto sensor = std::make_unique<SHT35Sensor>(0x03, serial.get(), sht35, 0);
    auto actual = sensor->execute(Instruction(0, 0, Bytes("\x02", 1)));
    ASSERT_TRUE(actual);
}
```

I want to isolate the first five lines of the test in order for them to be reused. I thought that it would be enough (and especially it would be correct) to do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<SHT35Sensor> prepare() {
    auto sht35 = SampleSHT35::create();
    sht35->add(22.4, 56.5);
    char writeBuffer[100] = {0};
    auto serial = std::make_unique<SampleSerial>("", writeBuffer, 0);
    return std::make_shared<SHT35Sensor>(0x03, serial.get(), sht35, 0);
}

TEST(SHT35Sensor, ValidInstruction) {
    auto sensor = prepare();
    auto actual = sensor->execute(Instruction(0, 0, Bytes("\x02", 1)));
    ASSERT_TRUE(actual);
}
```

Essentially, I moved the code in a function, and instead of `unique_ptr`, I used `shared_ptr` in order to be able to share it between the function which creates it and the caller.

However, the second variant leads to a segmentation fault when running the test, meaning that my understanding of smart pointers is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `serial.get()` returns pointer, but does not detaches it from unique_ptr, so when prepare ends - unique_ptr deletes SampleSerial instance and shared_ptr contains pointer to freed memory. You may use `serial.release()` or directly use shared_ptr

Comment: @marcinj: naturally, it was as easy as that. Can you please promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: FWIW, you can return function local `unique_ptr`'s, even though they can't be copied.  Function locals will get moved since they are expiring.

Comment: Did you write the class SHT35Sensor? You could change it so it has a shared_ptr or unique_ptr inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `serial.get()` returns pointer, but does not detaches it from `unique_ptr`, so when `prepare ends` - unique_ptr deletes `SampleSerial` instance and `shared_ptr` contains pointer to freed memory. You may use `serial.release()` or directly use `shared_ptr`.

Above answer assumes that `SHT35Sensor` will handle lifetime of `SampleSerial` instance. But if that is not true then pass `unique_ptr<SampleErial>` to `SHT35Sensor`:

```
return std::make_shared<SHT35Sensor>(0x03, std::move(serial), sht35, 0);
```

Your `SHT35Sensor` should accept `std::unique_ptr<SampleErial>` as second parameter - and pass it to class member using constructor initialization or once again `std::move`.

I would prefer the second solution as no bare pointer will be accepted by `SHT35Sensor` - which is good.

Comment: This solution is likely to leak memory. Who is going to delete that `release`d pointer then?

Comment: @Evg you are right, I will udpdate answer (but maybe SHT35Sensor does this, who knows:-))

Comment: If `SHT35Sensor` did that, the original code is likely to crash due to double detetion.